# Google gadget for Android Enthusiasts

Tags: discussion

Hi guys,

**This is not a question**

I made a small google widget for displaying your flair on iGoogle or another google service.

You can check it out @ http://www.google.fr/ig/adde?moduleurl=http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3505759/gmodules/android.xml&source=imag

Have a nice day, and let me know if you it to evolve.

Answer (score 0):

Hi folks,

Two month after, I'm seeking for enhance this small module ; do you think we should add something ?

Currently, 228 users are using it.

What about you ? Do you need something more ?

Thanks for your help

Rob

Comment: How hard would it be to make it into an Android widget that I could put on a home screen?

Comment: @travis That sounds like exactly what the SOFlair widget does https://market.android.com/details?id=org.ocactus.soflair

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to add this to (regular, non-hosted) gmail. I haven't added a lot of widgets, and I'm stumped

the gadget URL is http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3505759/gmodules/android.xml

It shows up, but is empty

[image: flair executes, but no content]

and the gadgets settings tells me I need to configure an ID (of course)... but I can't find a way to configure the ID.

[image: flair gadget needs configuration]

Does this not work for gmail -- which otherwise accepts gadgets --, or can I configure it?

Comment: Er, for the moment, I'm sorry but I can't check it. I'll be back today to try to fix it.